# Magento : Programmatically create order bundled products and configurable products

Tags: magento

I tried using the following code from [Vinai](http://netzarbeiter.com/) in creating an order but it only works in simple products. I already tried playing with the keys and values in $buyInfo but it seems the order won't proceed. I might be missing something?

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());

if ('do customer orders') {
        // for customer orders:
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                ->setWebsiteId(1)
                ->loadByEmail('customer@example.com');
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
} else {
        // for guesr orders only:
        $quote->setCustomerEmail('customer@example.com');
}

// add product(s)
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(8);
$buyInfo = array(
        'qty' => 1,
        // custom option id => value id
        // or
        // configurable attribute id => value id
);
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($buyInfo));

$addressData = array(
        'firstname' => 'Test',
        'lastname' => 'Test',
        'street' => 'Sample Street 10',
        'city' => 'Somewhere',
        'postcode' => '123456',
        'telephone' => '123456',
        'country_id' => 'US',
        'region_id' => 12, // id from directory_country_region table
);

$billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($addressData);
$shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($addressData);

$shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
                ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
                ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');

$quote->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'checkmo'));

$quote->collectTotals()->save();

$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();
$order = $service->getOrder();
```

Any idea on how to make it work also in bundled and configurable products? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To make a budle product you must set a prodtypeID to "bundle"

this is code im using:

```
    $__magproduct = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();



    // Build the product 
    $__magproduct->setSku(trim($sku_of_product)); 
    $__magproduct->setAttributeSetId('4');# 4 is for default 
    $__magproduct->setTypeId($prodtype); 
    $__magproduct->setName($getprodId->ProductName); 
    //$__magproduct->setCategoryIds(array(42)); # some cat id's, 
    $__magproduct->setWebsiteIDs(array(1)); # Website id, 1 is default 
    //$__magproduct->setDescription($getprodId->Description); 
    //$__magproduct->setShortDescription($getprodId->Description); 
    $__magproduct->setPrice($prodprice); # Set some price

    //Default Magento attribute 
    $__magproduct->setWeight($getprodId->Weight); 

    $__magproduct->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH); 
    $__magproduct->setStatus(1); 
    $__magproduct->setTaxClassId(2); # default tax class 


    $__magproduct->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')); 

    try { 
    $__magproduct->save(); 

    if (!($stockItem = $product->getStockItem())) {
                $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item');
                $stockItem->assignProduct($__magproduct)
                          ->setData('stock_id', 1)
                          ->setData('store_id', 1);
            }

            $stockItem->setData('qty', $qty)
                      ->setData('is_in_stock', $isinstock)
                      ->setData('manage_stock', 1)
                      ->setData('use_config_manage_stock', 0)
                      ->save();

        unset($__magproduct,$stockItem);
```

and after that insert a bundled options:

```
$productCheck = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku',$getprodId->Code);         
Mage::register('product', $productCheck);









          $position = 0;

          $optionRawData = array();

          $selectionRawData = array();
          $selectionRawData[0] = array();

         foreach ($materials as $material) {
                $material = (array) $material;

                $komponenta = $client->GetProductSimple($material["ProductID"]);
                $komponenta = (array) $komponenta;

                echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;assigned: ".$komponenta["Code"]." ".$komponenta["ProductName"]." ks(".$material["Count"].")<br>\n";  

                $itemSKU = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku(trim($getprodId->Code));
                $materialSKU = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku(trim($komponenta["Code"]));

                if (($itemSKU != "") && ($materialSKU != ""))
                    {

                $position++;

$optionRawData[$position] = array(
    'required' => 1,
    'option_id' => '',
    'position' => '',
    'type' => 'radio',
    'title' => 'Komponenta '.$komponenta["ProductName"],
    'default_title' => 'Komponenta '.$komponenta["ProductName"],
    'delete' => '',
);


$selectionRawData[$position][] = array(
    'product_id' => $materialSKU,
    'selection_qty' => $material["Count"],
    'selection_can_change_qty' => 0,
    'position' => 0,
    'is_default' => 1,
    'selection_id' => '',
    'selection_price_type' => 0,
    'selection_price_value' => 0.0,
    'option_id' => '',
    'delete' => ''
);






                    };

                unset($material,$komponenta,$itemSKU,$materialSKU);

         };




Mage::register('productCheck', $productCheck);
Mage::register('current_product', $productCheck);
$productCheck->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(false);
$productCheck->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
// Set the Bundle Options & Selection Data
$productCheck->setBundleOptionsData($optionRawData);
$productCheck->setBundleSelectionsData($selectionRawData);
$productCheck->setCanSaveBundleSelections(true);
$productCheck->setAffectBundleProductSelections(true);

$productCheck->save();
```

**Bunded item is not the same like Configurable!!**