# magento programmatically create order for configurable product

Tags: php, magento

I'm using custom script to create an order, it works fine for simple products which have no custom attributes.

Now I want to create an order for configureable products, like the product prices changes from original price to different with respect to product attributes selection.

I have an example of my demanding product, I have installed magento 1.7.0.2 with sample data which has a product [T-Shirt] with product id as 126, its original price is 13.5 and it is configurable product.

On item detail page, its prices changes by selecting [Size:Medium] & [Color:Green] to 18.75.

In my case I send its all information to my site.

On my site I get this product's SKU as 'zol_g_m' with specific quantity. Now I send its information on magento store to create order but my script on magento store consider it as simple product and create order for it with price as 13.5 not as 18.75

My script based on two function like this

```
    public function PrepareOrder($params, $paymentData, array $shippingAddress, array $billingAddress, $shippingMethod, $couponCode = null) 
{
    require_once 'app/Mage.php';
    $app = Mage::app();
    $req_result = array();
    Mage::register('isSecureArea', true);

    $customerModel = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $customerModel->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
    $customerObj = $customerModel->loadByEmail('abc@hotmail.com');  //with customer email

    $storeId=$customerObj->getStoreId();
    $quoteObj=Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->assignCustomer($customerObj); //sets ship/bill address
    $storeObj=$quoteObj->getStore()->load($storeId);
    $quoteObj->setStore($storeObj);
    $product_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku('zol_g_med');

    $productModel=Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $productObj=$productModel->load(129);
    $productObj->setSkipCheckRequiredOption(true); 
    $quoteItem=Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($productObj);
    $quoteItem->setQuote($quoteObj);
    $quoteItem->setQty($product_qty);
    $quoteObj->addItem($quoteItem);
    $productObj->unsSkipCheckRequiredOption(); 
    $quoteItem->checkData();                            

    $quoteObj->getPayment()->importData(array('method' => 'ccsave', 
    'cc_owner' => $paymentData['cc_owner'],
    'cc_type' => $paymentData['cc_type'],
    'cc_number' => $paymentData['cc_number'],
    'cc_exp_month' => $paymentData['cc_exp_month'],
    'cc_exp_year' => $paymentData['cc_exp_year'],
    'cc_cid' => $paymentData['cc_cid']));

    // addresses
    $quoteShippingAddress = new Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address();
    $quoteShippingAddress->setData($shippingAddress);
    $quoteBillingAddress = new Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address();
    $quoteBillingAddress->setData($billingAddress);
    $quoteObj->setShippingAddress($quoteShippingAddress);
    $quoteObj->setBillingAddress($quoteBillingAddress);

    // coupon code
    $quoteObj->getShippingAddress()->setShipping_method($shippingMethod)->setShippingDescription($shippingMethod);   
    $quoteObj->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);   //
    $quoteObj->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();   //

    $quoteObj -> addMessage('Auto Order Code');   //after separately            
    $quoteObj->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
    $quoteObj->getShippingAddress()->unsetData('cached_items_all');
    $quoteObj->getShippingAddress()->unsetData('cached_items_nominal');
    $quoteObj->getShippingAddress()->unsetData('cached_items_nonnominal');
    $quoteObj->collectTotals();
    //end shipping charges block

    $quoteObj->setIsActive(0);     //if it is commented the shopping cart has last order items against customer logged in, also the order is displayed in my account block in frontend
    $quoteObj->save();
    $quoteId=$quoteObj->getId();
    return $quoteId;
}   


    public function createOrderCustom($quoteId,$cartData) 
{
    $status_arr = array();
    $quoteObj = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId); // Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
    $items = $quoteObj->getAllItems();
    $quoteObj->reserveOrderId();        
    // convert quote to order
    $convertQuoteObj = Mage::getSingleton('sales/convert_quote');
    $orderObj = $convertQuoteObj->addressToOrder($quoteObj->getShippingAddress());      
    // convert quote addresses
    $orderObj->setBillingAddress($convertQuoteObj->addressToOrderAddress($quoteObj->getBillingAddress()));
    $orderObj->setShippingAddress($convertQuoteObj->addressToOrderAddress($quoteObj->getShippingAddress()));        
    // set payment options
    $orderObj->setPayment($convertQuoteObj->paymentToOrderPayment($quoteObj->getPayment()));        
    // convert quote items
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // @var $item Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item
        $item->setOriginalPrice($item->getProduct()->getPrice());
        $orderItem = $convertQuoteObj->itemToOrderItem($item);          
    //custom block of code to add/show product attributes/optinns, ***STAR FROM HERE...............................................//
    $existentOptions['additional_options'] = array();
    $current_product_id = '';
    $current_product_id =  $item->getProductId();
    foreach($cartData as $part){
        $productIdBySkuManual = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($part['product_sku']);
            if(($current_product_id==$productIdBySkuManual) && isset($part['attributes']) && sizeof($part['attributes'])>0){
                if($part['attributes']['attribute']['label']!='' && $part['attributes']['attribute']['value']!=''){ 
                        $existentOptions['additional_options'][] = array(
                            'label' => $part['attributes']['attribute']['label'],
                            'value' => $part['attributes']['attribute']['value'],
                            'print_value' => $part['attributes']['attribute']['print_value']
                        );
                }else{
                    foreach($part['attributes']['attribute'] as $ic_product_options){   
                        $existentOptions['additional_options'][] = array(
                            'label' => $ic_product_options['label'],
                            'value' => $ic_product_options['value'],
                            'print_value' => $ic_product_options['print_value']
                        );
                    }   
                }
            }
    }       
    $orderItem->setProductOptions($existentOptions);
    $existentOptions['additional_options']='';                  
    if ($productOptions = $item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)->getOrderOptions($item->getProduct())) {
//                $productOptions['info_buyRequest']['options'] = prepareOptionsForRequest($item);
        $options = $productOptions;
    }

    if ($addOptions = $item->getOptionByCode('additional_options')) {
        $options['additional_options'] = unserialize($addOptions->getValue());
    }
    if ($options) {
        //$orderItem->setProductOptions($options);
    }
    if ($item->getParentItem()) {
        $orderItem->setParentItem($orderObj->getItemByQuoteItemId($item->getParentItem()->getId()));
    }
    $orderObj->addItem($orderItem);
    }

    $orderObj->setCanShipPartiallyItem(false);
    $orderObj->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_NEW, true);

    try {
        $orderObj->place();
    } catch (Exception $e){     
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        Mage::log($e->getTraceAsString());
    }
    //$orderObj->sendNewOrderEmail(); //it doesnot work
    $orderObj->setEmailSent(true);
    $orderObj->save(); 
    $last_insert_order_id = $orderObj->getRealOrderId();
    return $last_insert_order_id;
}
```

Please help is required to adjust this code for configurable product, so order is placed with price on the basis of attributes selection.

Comment: I have a similar question bookmarked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528599

Comment: Hi Chris, have you got any solution yet

Answer (score 2):

Don't handcraft your quotes with `$quote->addItem()`, there's too much to consider and it's not necessary at all to make it complicated.

What you need instead is `$quote->addProduct()`. The method has the following signature:

```
 /**
  * Add product to quote
  *
  * return error message if product type instance can't prepare product
  *
  * @param mixed $product
  * @param null|float|Varien_Object $request
  * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item|string
  */
  public function addProduct(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $request = null)
```

`$request` can either be just a number (the quantity) or a `Varien_Object` that contains all data which a "add to cart" request would send. You need this for configurable products:

> ## Which data can $buyRequest contain?
>
> Besides product and qty it is bundle options for bundle products,
>   configurable attributes for configurable products, selected links for
>   downloadable products and custom options.
>
> ### All product types
>
> - **product**: the product ID
> - **qty**: Requested quantity. When the quantity in the quote item or    wishlist item changes, it is adjusted here as well.
> - **original_qty**: In case that the value of qty has changed, original_qty    contains the originally requested quantity.
> - **reset_count**: is used for updating items in the cart [...]
> - Further request parameters from the add to cart form that are not    relevant for the quote generation:
>
>   - **related_product**
>   - **uenc**
>   - **form_key**
>
> ### Configurable Products
>
> - **super_attribute**: Array with the configured attributes in the form
>     `attribute_id => value_id`

[(Source)](http://www.schmengler-se.de/en/2014/09/magento-info_buyrequest-objekt-referenz/)

The minimal request object for your configurable product will look like this:

```
new Varien_Object(array(
    'qty' => $qty,
    'super_attribute' => [ $sizeAttribute->getId() => $valueMedium, $colorAttribute->getId() => $valueGreen ]
));
```

This should point you in the right direction.